# Java 11 - java/beans/PropertyChangeListener

Tags: java-11, propertychangelistener

Getting below with java11. This was working fine with java 8. Please suggest.
This is happening only when running in eclipse 4.12
Is there a way we can add module java.desktop when compliance level is 1.8 in eclipse.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/beans/PropertyChangeListener
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.my.cep.driver.http.server.impl.TomcatServer.init(TomcatServer.java:155)
    at com.my.cep.driver.http.MyChannel.init(MyChannel.java:78)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the resolution to above issue.

Ad below in vm arguments to resolve.

--add-modules java.xml,java.sql,java.prefs,java.desktop